# How to create key value pair JSON array

Tags: jquery

I have an array as shown below from which i am trying to create a key value

```
var text = ["One","TWO","THREE"];

var myarray = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
{
var name = text[i];
var toaddstr = 'CNX'
myarray.push(name+":"+toaddstr);
}
console.log(myarray);
});
```

When i run the above program the output i am getting is

```
["One:CNX", "TWO:CNX", "THREE:CNX"]
```

IS it possible to create an array as this way

```
[
"One": "CNX",
"TWO": "CNX",
"THREE": "CNX"
]
```

This is my fiddle , please let me know how to do this

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/424/

Comment: `[
"One": "CNX",
"TWO": "CNX",
"THREE": "CNX"
]` is  invalid JSON and JS object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you're trying to create is not syntactically correct, you can't have key/value pairs in an array. However, you could use an object instead:

```js
var obj = {};
["One", "TWO", "THREE"].forEach(function(v) {
  obj[v] = 'CNX';
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following format:

```
[
"One": "CNX",
"TWO": "CNX",
"THREE": "CNX"
]
```

Is not a valid one. It should be:

```
{
  "One": "CNX",
  "TWO": "CNX",
  "THREE": "CNX"
}
```

To do that:

```js
var text = ["One", "TWO", "THREE"];

var myarray = {};

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var name = text[i];
  var toaddstr = 'CNX'
  myarray[name] = toaddstr;
}
console.log(myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an object (which is a JS map), not an array. See your new code below.

```
var text = ["One","TWO","THREE"];

var myarray = {};

$( document ).ready(function() {
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
{
var name = text[i];
var toaddstr = 'CNX'
myarray[name] = toaddstr;
}
console.log(myarray);
});
```